# Map Reduce Output in Mongo DB is incorrect in a Sharded Cluster

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, sharding

I have been using Mongo DB as a standalone instance for doing some analysis with my data.

But with my data size growing, I started experimenting with Mongo DB Cluster.

My cluster configuration is as follows:

3 machines (2 core CPU, 2 GB RAM, 30 GB Hard Disk)

1) Machine 1 - mongos, mongod, mongo config server (Hostname-config2)

2) Machine 2 - mongod, mongo config server (Hostname-config3)

3) Machine 3 - mongo config server (Hostname-config1)

I have used Map-Reduce functionality of MongoDB and I have observed that in case of a sharded cluster, map-reduce gives incorrect output when output is directed to a sharded collection. This issue has not been observed in case of a standalone mongo instance.

I have an input collection named "user_data" and an output collection named "intermediate_data". I tried executing map-reduce code on both single instance mongo and mongo cluster and the checked number of entries in "intermediate_data" collection.

Following was the output in a standalone instance (which is the correct output):

> MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
>
> connecting to: test
>
> use analysis_data_shekhar_test
>
> switched to db analysis_data_shekhar_test
>
> db.intermediate_data.find().itcount()
>
> 1090900

Mongo Cluster:

> mongos> use analysis_data_shekhar_test
>
> switched to db analysis_data_shekhar_test
>
> mongos> db.intermediate_data.find().itcount()
>
> 934832

I observed mongod.log in one of the shards of the mongo cluster where it shows output count as 1090900 (which is the correct number of output rows) but number of rows in the collection(934832) is much less than this:

> Mon Jan  6 22:45:05.352 [conn139] command analysis_data_shekhar_test.$cmd command: { mapreduce.shardedfinish: { mapreduce: "user_data", map: function(){
>                    var sid = this.sid;
>                    var ..., reduce: function(mac, mac_info_list) {
>               var result ={loclist_07:[],cou..., scope: { bitmap30: 4294967166, bitmap14: 4278190206, num7: 7, bitmap7: 2147483774, num14: 14, num30: 30 }, query: { sid: { $in: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] } }, out: { merge: "intermediate_data", sharded: true } }, inputDB: "analysis_data_shekhar_test", shardedOutputCollection: "tmp.mrs.user_data_1389028296_86", shards: { config3:27018: { result: "tmp.mrs.user_data_1389028296_86", splitKeys: [ { _id: { mac: "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa", ssid: "ABC" } }, { _id: { mac: "bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb", ssid: "" } }, { _id: { mac: "cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc", ssid: "XYZ" } }, { _id: { mac: "dd:dd:dd:dd:dd:dd", ssid: "" } }, { _id: { mac: "ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee", ssid: "" } }, { _id: { mac: "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", ssid: "XYZ" } } ], timeMillis: 183410, counts: { input: 596103, emit: 1192206, reduce: 89217, output: **1090900** }, ok: 1.0 } }, shardCounts: { config3:27018: { input: 596103, emit: 1192206, reduce: 89217, output: **1090900** } }, counts: { emit: 1192206, input: 596103, output: **1090900**, reduce: 89217 } } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) W:2509 w:12843472 reslen:721 23709ms

Can someone please let me know why is the row count in the collection less than what is shown as "out" count in the logs?

I tried searching on google and stackoverflow for similar issues but did not find any results.

Please help.

Comment: It's unfortunate such a thing is happening.. Could it be because of some bug in the mongo MR framework?

Comment: I have this issue as well, using mongodb 3.2, running m/r query via node.js

Comment: seems to be a reported issue currently marked as closed - can't reproduce.